# What capacitor needs to be used for a circuit that limits the current?

Tags: pcb, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, current-limiting

I have the following circuit that is intended to limit the current that passes through diode D1

[image]

In this case, we can see on the graph that the current is limited at 5.31mA

We can see on the graph what happens to the voltage at the cathode of **D5** (blue line) and the current at **D5** (green line).

The input voltage is red line.

[image]

Instead of **R8** i will have the IC BD9G101G that gives me an output voltage of **3.3V**, and from the datasheet it says that it's input will need to be between **6V** to **42V**. 
I actually have it connected in the following way:

[image]

- Will i need to be careful with the value i choose for the capacitor in a way that it gives the desired voltage?
- Another thing that i believe it's not good is that at the terminal of **R8** the voltage will not be stable and that doesn't seem to be good for the IC that will be there instead of the resistor.
- Or even if there is a better solution than using a BD9G101G that gives me the desired 3.3V output i'm open to replace it.

EDIT: i edited the circuits to be similar to what i really have.
The ideia of the current limiter is to make the circuit draw as little current as possible from the voltage source.

Comment: Please explain why you are attempting to limit current to your BD9G101G.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get context of having limited current of \$2.7\, \mathrm{mA}\$. however, regarding the capacitor:

The capacitor recommended value is \$ 4.7\, \mathrm{uF}\$. Other than that, voltage rating of the capacitor should be more than the expected input voltage. Since, the IC input voltage is rated upto \$42\, \mathrm{V}\$, a \$50\, \mathrm{V}\$ capacitor has been recommeded.

---

> **Input Capacitor**:
>   In order to reduce input ripple, mount ceramic capacitor of low ESR near the VCCpin. In  the  BD9G101G,  it  is 
>   recommended  the  4.7μF  or  more  capacitorvalue.  In  case  of 
>   using  the  electrolytic  capacitor, *mount about 1μF ceramic capacitor
>   in parallel in order to prevent oscillation*

- go for Ceramic capacitor if cost is not the issue
- The current limitation at the input side may demand bigger capacitor (depending on the load)

  ---

**Edit 2**: since the input current is limited, the BD9G101G might not achieve a good load regulation (responding as fast as possible to the changing load). If you have the estimate of peak current demand form the load of BD9G101G,then you can estimate the required value of the capacitor so that, the main circuit will not be burdened. The capacitors will slowly charge back to normal voltage via the limited current path.

Comment: Hi @Umar. The context of limiting the current is to prevent the circuit to draw much current from the source. I will have a lot more circuits connected to the "voltage source" which will draw current too.